# Smart contract doesn't get deployed on Rinkeby

Tags: rinkeby, hardhat

I wrote my first contract for NFT and when I deploy it I cannot find it on Rinkeby. Funny enough, it always deploys to same address every time I run script. It also doesn't take any ether away from my Rinkeby wallet.

CLI output:

> npx run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby
> Watching /Users/fran/NFT and all sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore.
> Will not monitor dotfiles.
> Found & ignored ./artifacts ; is listed in .gitignore
> Found & ignored ./cache ; is listed in .gitignore
> Found & ignored ./node_modules ; is listed in .gitignore
>
> Starting: scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby Contract deployed to
> 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
> ^C

Deploy script:

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
  const nft = await NFT.deploy();
  await nft.deployed();
  console.log("Contract deployed to", nft.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Config:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  networks:{
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.RINKEBY_URL, //https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/lX2-n0QN-I72N87f6E.....
      accounts: [ process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: does your privatekey start with 0x?, yoou are probably using the private key of other address. 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 exists on Rinkeby

Comment: no it doesn't :(